# cmd batch rename subfolders/files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

how can i batch rename the files from folder A which contains subfolders and files with this format name filename_ex.doc and make them look like filename.doc?

i've been trying to do this for awhile now and it's been an epic fail. please help.

Comment: @MartinJames Whenever I am trying batch "programming", I fail so huge, that I never ever would post any of the code snippets I developed during these steps ;-)

Comment: i've tried FOR /F , FOR /D all those things and read the docu from here: [link](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) . No decent result so far... :( I really hate windows batch programming.

Comment: @MartinJames: also tried from the command line: `for "tokens=1-3 delims=_." %a ('dir *_ex.ext') do echo %a_%b.%c` ... this is gets jammed if i have the PATH with folders/subfolders or other files containing the chars: "." and "_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you want to rename the files in the subfolders as well, which is where you had problems with the direction in your 2nd comment to Martin James. I'm guessing you tried that code with the DIR /S option. But you were so close :-) You just needed to use 2 loops!

***Edit - fixed code*** Once the output looks correct, drop the ECHO to make it functional.

```
@echo off
for /r %%D in (.) do (
  pushd "%%~fD"
  for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=_." %%A in ('dir /b *_ex.ext 2^>nul') do echo ren "%%A_%%B.%%C" "%%A.%%C"
  popd
)
```

The above will work as long as each file name does not have any `_` or `.` other than what appears in `_ex.ext`. Characters in the path should not be any problem, just the file name is a concern.

Here is a more robust solution that should work with any filename (except unicode names). It is also significantly faster. It uses a substring operation, and you must know the number of characters to strip from the name. In your example it is 3 characters. Again, remove ECHO once the resultant commands look correct.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s *_ex.ext') do (
  set "old=%%F"
  set "new=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo ren "!old!" "!new:~0,-3!.ext"
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: would this work if you have underscores in the names of the subfolders and filenames?

Comment: i've tested it. it doesn't work, but i'll check what's wrong. thanks

Comment: @Alex - I'll say it didn't work. I fixed 2 bugs, and added a more robust and faster alternative.